# How to import other module in index.d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

## Background

I'm making react-naive app with typescript. I'm using [react-native-voice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voice) javascript library. It doesn't have a type declaration file. So I made it in `myproject/src/@types/react-native-voice/index.d.ts` like below.

```
declare module "react-native-voice" {
  type Option = {
    EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL: string,
    ...
  }
  type StartEvent = {
    error: boolean
  }
  ....
  function start(locale: Locale, options?: Option): Promise<{}>
  function stop(): Promise<{}>
  function onSpeechPartialResults(e: PartialResults): void
  ....
}
```

Notice the locale argument. The react-native-voice library's start function accepts locale property. That is just a string. But I wanted to make it enum like below.

```
enum Locale {
  en_US = 'en-US',
  ko_KR = 'ko-KR',
  ja_JP = 'ja-JP',
  zh_CN = 'zh-CN',
  zh_HK = 'zh_HK',
  zh = 'zh'
}
```

And I put this into `declare module "react-native-voice" { enum Locale.... }`, the same place.

## Problem

When I use react-native-voice with my custom index.d.ts file, I got runtime error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ko_KR' of undefined
```

Yes, there is no Locale variable in react-native-voice's javascript source code. I understand this error.

So, I moved `enum Locale` into my `constants.ts` file and tried to import it from `index.d.ts`.

```
// index.d.ts
import {Locale} from '../../constants';

declare module "react-native-voice" { ... }
```

But, suddenly VSCode shows error.

```
Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'react-native-voice' resolves to an untyped module at 'my-project-path/node_modules/react-native-voice/index.js', which cannot be augmented.ts(2665)
```

What does this mean? and what should I do to import `enum Locale` from `constants.ts` in `index.d.ts` file?

Comment: `enum`s generate code, so they can't be ambient. You can use a string literal to accomplish the same thing. `type Local = 'en-US' | 'ko-KR' | ...` https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html

Comment: @Tyler Sebastian Thanks. But Is there no way to import another module in `index.d.ts` file? `index.d.ts` file should be independent?

Comment: @ByeonginYoon you can leverage declaration merging instead of importing other modules https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: Declaration merging suggestions are great, but in this case you would do better to dispense with the enum entirely and type the parameter using a union of string literal types.